# custom sorting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['msft', 'tsla', 'amd', 'bac'], 'close': [102, 100, 35, 30]})
```

I want to sort the `df` using a custom order of `sym` column.

My desired outcome looks like this:

```
   sym  close
0   bac     30
1  tsla    100
2  msft    102
3   amd     35
```

Comment: Hello! Could you explain the logic behind your custom order?. Is not lexicographical order, so what is?

Comment: It is custom ! Is it possible?

Comment: looks arbitrary for now

Comment: There is no way to do this simple thing?!!

Comment: Please be more specific. Custom according to what, the actual values in the sym column? So to sort them using some list or dictionary containing those items?

Comment: Yes, is possible, but what I am asking is: is there a logic which can be implemented into a custom sorting algorithm or is just you picking a new order for the row? The approach is different.

Comment: yes using some kind of list or dic . Just give me a code with this output plz.

Comment: @Valentino I just want a new order. It does't have logic.

Comment: `df1.loc[[3,1,0,2]].reset_index(drop=True)` Btw saying things like _"Just give me a code with this output plz"_ to people who are helping you in their free time is not very kind

Answer (score 1):

Given that this seems to be a very arbitrary order, I think that your best option is to add another column that represents the order that you would like the elements in, sorting by the order of those values and then dropping said column from the dataframe. However, depending on the size of your dataframe, this could be a lot of work. Then again, sorting a large dataframe arbitrarily will be a lot of work regardless.

So, what you could do:

```
df1['order']=[3,2,4,1]
df1.sort_values(by='order', inplace=True)
df1.drop('order', axis=1,inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `numpy.argsort` to specify the order you want.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['msft', 'tsla', 'amd', 'bac'], 'close': [102, 100, 35, 30]})
df1 = df1.loc[np.argsort([2, 1, 3, 0])].reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   sym  close
0   bac     30
1  tsla    100
2  msft    102
3   amd     35
```

Comment: Also works without `reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: this will give a slightly different output, but yes, the `sym` and `close` colums will stay the same